# having issues when working on Deep learning project on my mac mini M2 setup

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

i am trying to use pretrained model ESRGAN, i've clone the repo from github  and downloaded weights from Gdrive but when i am trying to run my script it gives me and error

```
  raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

How can I invoke my M2 Gpu for deep learning Projects

Comment: Check if your pytorch version is cuda_enabled by running `torch.cuda.is_available()`? If yes, then check the code and see if any file have the line `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ...`. You may try to comment that line out or change that to `0`

Comment: Ya Thanks, Cow 
I've tried with MPS. It works for 5 minutes but then starts to crash because my m2 chip memory isn't enough so I can run deep learning projects I am trying to find some other options, like having a cloud platform or any cloud instance 

by the way thanks for the time that you gave me an advice 
appreciate Cow